# c++ optimization of image resize array

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

Trying to increase the width of an image array to return to an opencv mat. The problem is speed when the temp_mat array needs to be shifted by a certain amount as the image increases in size. See function below:

This line will run with good speed:

```
//temp_mat[height][width] = in_mat[i][j];
```

But the speed decreases by a lot when changed to:

```
temp_mat[height][width + int(((width - middle_point) * -1) * FLOAT_HERE)] = in_mat[i][j];
```

The loop takes many milliseconds longer to run. Here is the complete function, variable names have been changed.

```
#define D_HEIGHT 1000
#define D_WIDTH 1200

int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 1000;
int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1200;
float FLOAT_HERE = .04;
static int temp_mat[D_HEIGHT][D_WIDTH];

cv::Mat get_mat(int in_mat[D_HEIGHT][300]){
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int middle_point = DEFAULT_WIDTH/2;

    for(int i=0;i < DEFAULT_HEIGHT;i++){
        width = 0;
        for(int j =0;j < DEFAULT_WIDTH / 4;j++){
            for(int il = 0; il < DEFAULT_WIDTH / (DEFAULT_WIDTH/4); il++){
                //This is to slow, but what I need
                temp_mat[height][width + int(((width - middle_point) * -1) * FLOAT_HERE)] = in_mat[i][j];
                //This is ok
                //temp_mat[height][width] = in_mat[i][j];
                width++;
            }
        }
        height++;
    }
    return cv::Mat(D_HEIGHT,D_WIDTH,CV_8UC4,temp_mat);
}
```

Any ideas to make it faster are welcome. I am hoping to avoid a new thread.

Comment: why you have `o(DEFAULT_WIDTH^3)` complexity? Defenetlyt you ahve to many `for` loops. In fact why you do not use some openCV API for that task?

Comment: do you mean build the opencv mat first, then stretch it outwards, then shift all outer points inwards to the center using a particular formula? If this is better I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing that wrong just use [Affine Transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) and OpenCV will do this in fastest possible way.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `DEFAULT_WIDTH` is not declared `const` it appears to be used as a constant, and the naming of the variable suggests it as well. You should probably make it constant, even though that in it self will not improve performance. I say this because you are calculating a `middle_point` that is then also constant, and can be pre calculated. The same goes for the `FLOAT_HERE`, which also appears to be constant.

Having made those constant the only variable in the calculation, which you make multiple times is the `width` variable. Since you are always looping the same number of iterations, you might consider pre-calculating the different values, simply creating a cache of values instead of calculating on the fly.

For each value of width you can create a corresponding calculated value, you can store this in an array where the index is the width, and the value is what is calculated:

```
int width_cache[DEFAULT_WIDTH];

...

for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_WIDTH; ++i) {
    width_cache[i] = i + int(((i - middle_point) * -1) * FLOAT_HERE);
}
```

In your loop, you could then do:

```
temp_mat[height][width_cache[width]] = in_mat[i][j];
```